Selenium on Edge with IE Mode(IE Driver) opening a popup window on IE browser which causes 'system detected an overrun of a stack based buffer' error
Selenium on Edge with IE Mode(IE Driver) opening a popup window on IE browser which causes 'system detected an overrun of a stack based buffer' error
Selenium opens Edge Browser in IE mode using IE driver
When code clicks on a link using javascriptexecutor which opens a popup window but in IE Browser and instantly gets 'system detected an overrun of a stack based buffer in this application' ieplorer.ee System Error
And code fails
-- Looking to open popup window in Edge only with IE driver.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I need the popup window to be open on Edge browser and not on IE browser. I am using Edge in IE Mode.
